# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist)

Tags: java, oracle

I am getting the following exception, although I have the table present in my schema and also

I have the grant to create a table.

```
RequestDAOImplBean;ERROR;DataAccessException : PreparedStatementCallback;
 bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO okarmacompl.SERVICE_REQUEST_FAULT (SERVICE_REQUEST_ID, FAULT_CODE, DESCRIPTION, PARAMETER_NAME, TYPE, SERVICE_REQUEST_FAULT_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, okarmacompl.SEQUENCESERVICEREQUESTFAULT.nextval)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What could be the possible reason for this

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct schema? I mean a schema from where okarmacompl.SERVICE_REQUEST_FAULT is accessible and has been given INSERT GRANT?

You also need to have grant to insert into that table. "grant to create table" is entirely different.

Comment: i am able to insert values in service_request_fault through sql developer

Comment: Is 'okarmacompl.SEQUENCESERVICEREQUESTFAULT.nextval' is your view.? If yes is it returning value from sql developer.?

Comment: yes its returning values and it's a sequence

Comment: from which schema are you able to insert into service_request_fault??
Is that schema same as the one you are logging into via JAVA code?
Please ensure this.

Comment: OKARMACOMPL schema as mentioned in insert

Comment: i am able o insert the values through sql developer

Comment: This has to be a different schema issue or grant or synonym issue.  I am always skeptical when someone says, "it works in tool xyz, but not in this other tool."

Comment: @user2940216 Kindly post your java code which has connections details part to connect to your database schema.